# Проблема с добавлением нового документа в коллекцию Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firestore

Есть функция, которая регистрирует нового пользователя, а потом отправляет его данные в firestore.
С первой своей задачей она справляется, но со второй в какой-то момент разработки перестала. Из другого места в коде она работает, то есть если добавлять пользователя в базу при добавлении первого поста, например, то все работает.
Но сразу после регистрации нет, несмотря на наличие всех необходимых для этого данных. Самое удивительное, что на работала на протяжении длительного времени, но в один момент перестала. Опыта пока мало, не могу даже представить что может вызвать такую проблему.

```
export const signUpThunk = (name, email, password) => dispatch => {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => {
                firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).set({ // не работает
                        name,
                        email
                    })
                dispatch(setUserId(auth.currentUser.uid)) // Это срабатывает правильно с новым uid
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема по всей видимости была в настройках приватности firestore.
Эти настройки по какой-то причине не позволяли вести запись в базу залогиненому пользователю.

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
      }
    }
```

С этими настройками все работало:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Решение: по всей видимости запрос на запись в базу данных информации о новом пользователе отправлялся слишком быстро после регистрации этого пользователя и request.auth на тот момент равнялся null. Запись при настройке request.auth == null в firestore осуществлялась. При задержке отправки запроса на запись в firestore на 100 мс все работает с включенными настройками приватности. Ниже рабочий код:

```
export const signUpThunkAC = (name, email, password) => dispatch => {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((response) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    usersCollection.doc(response.user.uid).set({
                        name,
                        email
                    })
                    dispatch(setUserId(auth.currentUser.uid))
                }, 100)
            })
}
```

И настройки приватности firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create, read, write, update: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Рабочий код без setTimeout, который срабатывает при авторизации нового пользователя:

```
    export const signUpThunkAC = (name, email, password) => dispatch => {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(() => {
                    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                        if (user) {
                          usersCollection.doc(auth.currentUser.uid).set({
                                    name,
                                    email
                                })
                                dispatch(setUserId(auth.currentUser.uid))
                        }
                    });
                })
    }
```